# ESP32 how to encrypt / decrypt using the flash encryption AES256 key

Tags: aes, esp32, esp-idf

I've got flash encryption set up in my project, as per the normal instructions in ESP-IDF.

I know that there are a variety of ways, in the ESP-IDF to encrypt stuff when you write it to flash or decrypt it when you read it off of flash. But I want to encrypt and decrypt an arbitrary blob of data, so I can broadcast it over ESP-IDF.

I'd like to use the same AES256 key, as the same key will be burned to all my boards. So using the standard software AES tools that ESP-IDF provides, where you set your own encryption key, won't work well for me.

Is there any way I can use the underlying encrypt/decrypt methods that use the hidden flash encryption key that is burned in the efuse system?

Thanks!